# Raspberry Pi Plex

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to get the Plex Media Server to work on my Raspberry Pi.
When I start it with ./start.sh, I get the following error:

> ./Plex Media Server: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.47.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I edited the start.sh file and changed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH path to my current dir, where the lib files are located. But it shows me the same error..

Comment: Try adding links in your library directory, named `libboost_system.so.1.47.0` and refering to your current version of libboost_system.

Comment: Did you try to install `libboost-system` with `sudo apt-get install libbost-system-dev` or something like that?